# PHP sessions *not always* working

Tags: php, session, vps

I've recently migrated a bunch of websites to a new VPS and I've been having a lot of trouble with PHP sessions. All the websites are pretty much configured the same way, but there is one website where the sessions don't always work. The thing that bugs me is it's kind of random. I can go on the website, log in, and the session will work fine. Then, I go back a hour later, try to log in on the same account, but it doesn't keep my session anymore.

The VPS is running on **CentOS 5.8** and it has **PHP 5.4.3**. I should mention that before the migration, the website was running on PHP **5.3**.

I have checked the **session.save.path** and it is fine. I can even see the session files (with the correct user and everything) but they are empty when the sessions are not working, which makes sense. But why does it sometimes work, and sometimes it doesn't? I'm having trouble figuring this one out.

Comment: Have you got `session_start();` at top of EVERY page using them?

Comment: Yes I do. In fact, when the sessions *do* work, I can go on any page without any problems. When they don't, I can't go on a single page without losing my session.

Comment: Hmm... in the browser are there any cookies left over from viewing it on the old servers? they can cause oddities.

Comment: Also (sorry for such a comment)... made sure session path is writeable? Correct user/group ownership etc etc?

Comment: Sessions are binded to domain, for instance abc.com and www.abc.com are separate. Are you sure you are using exact same paths everywhere in code?

Comment: Hmm, I just tried to clear them and tried on another browser but the problem persists.

Comment: I checked and the ownership is fine. Even setting chmod 777 doesn't fix it. As for the domain, it would be surprising but I guess I should check that. I'm not the one who made the website and it was working fine on the old server but stil... When I test it, it doesn't seem to redirect me to another domain though.

Answer (score 4):

Sessions require server disk space to save has the server got disk space to save the session? we had a problem on a linux box where sessions stopped saving as its partition had run out of disk space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Good guess, I forgot to check that. Unfortunately, that's not the problem. I still have a lot of space on my VPS and I configured the website (in my Plesk panel) so that it can use as much space as it needs to on the server.

Answer (score 1):

check your php.ini, do a phpinfo() and see how sessions are configured... look especially for the session.gc_maxlifetime setting.

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Comment: All settings are pretty much like the default php settings, except for one thing : session.gc_divisor which is set to 1000 instead of the default 100. I'm not sure what it does actually.

Comment: For future generations... session.gc_divisor coupled with session.gc_probability defines the probability that the gc (garbage collection) process is started on every session initialization. The probability is calculated by using gc_probability/gc_divisor, e.g. 1/100 means there is a 1% chance that the GC process starts on each request. session.gc_divisor defaults to 100. @Y0lk

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem too. 
We solve it by changing session.auto_start = 0 to session.auto_start = 1 in the php.ini of the server. I don't know why but it solved our problem. We're still investigating why this worked and what are the consequences of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same issue sometime, with one of my dedicated server, which has PHP 5.4.3 installed.

Ironically, when I clear the browser cache(everything from beginning).

It works fine.